# Unable to call Web Services after upgrading JRE to 8u65

Tags: java, web-services, iis, web

I have a web service hosted on IIS on windows machine. Everything went fine until I upgraded Java to JRE 8u65.

Now it is throwing the below exception on invoking the web service.

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of
>   file from server  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown
>   Source)

Note : Previously I was using JRE 8u60. Any help in this regard is really helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the webservice over https ?

Comment: I am guessing a certificate authority certificate was installed in the old JRE's cacerts and now with the new JRE this is not done.
But this is a blind guess.
Verify the old JRE still works.

Comment: Thanks! Old JRE works

Comment: @rjdkolb - Interesting theory, but I would have thought that would give a different client-side exception, and a different stacktrace.  The client wouldn't be able to send the HTTP request (because SSL/TLS negotiation would have failed) but the stacktrace implies that that the request has been sent and the client is now trying to read the server's reply.

Comment: Stephen C , true, it's at the socket layer not at the TLS layer. Like you said in your answer, @Srik91 needs to look in the logs, there is probably more info there. The question is to little to go on

Comment: In the event viewer, I can see this error being populated for every request.

event id 36888 schannel fatal alert was generated 20

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace you have shown us comes from a Java client for your web service.  What is saying is that the server has closed the network connection before sending an HTTP response.

There is no evidence in this stacktrace to say why the web service did that.  The evidence is probably in the service logs.

Comment: But the same web service is working fine if I use JRE 8u60, that seems to be an issue in the latest one for me.